# Can I add an web alias programmatically to desktop in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, web, alias

As the title mentioned, can I add an alias linking to a specified web URL at the destop of Mac OS X programmatically?

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: @trojanfoe Maybe not. I am working on OS X application.